# jqGrid get rowid on the first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'd like to have my jqGrid first column to be the rowid

```
number | name | class
1 | A | acceptable
2 | B | good
3 | C | bad
```

or add first column like this (picture)

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxi6bFcYZ_MgYTI1dUJCMWEtd0E/edit

how to get the rowID in jqGrid on the first column by setting the option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you mean row number instead of rowID. To add column with row number you can add `rownumbers: true` option to jqGrid. If you really need to display rowid, then you have to extend `colModel` with the corresponding column and fill the values for the column exactly like you fill the data of all other columns.

Additionally I would recommend you to use `height: "auto"` option to improve visibility of the grid or to use alternatively `scrollOffset: 0` option which will remove unneeded place on the side of the grid reserved for the vertical scroll bar.